# Parts of mesh move off rig when moving certain bones

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I've made a humanoid character rig, pretty much directly following a tutorial, and I've run into an issue after weight painting where moving the bones in the spine of my character moves unrelated parts of the mesh. I will include an image of before and after a rotation on the first spine bone to illustrate.

[image: Before Spine 1 Rotation]
[image: After Spine 1 Rotation]

I have checked the weight painting, and they should all be normalized, and the first spine bone doesnt even have any influence on the lower bones. I will also include an image of my armature hierarchy as I thought maybe I had parented wrong.

[image: Armature Hierarchy]

Additionally, I realize that the eye is a separate object. I have found changing this does not affect the outcome, it is parented to a single bone and works as I would like. I have also seen another answer on this site to a slightly related question which said I should enable preserve volumes, but this did nothing.

I've gone through a good number of tutorials and I have some experience rigging in Maya, but not sure what to do about this.

Comment: Normalized weight groups can still be incorrect. If you just move the leg bone, does the model behave correctly?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Actually I managed to figure this one out yeah. There were a tonne of zero weights, fixing that I managed to get the rig working alright, though still a lot of smoothing to do. Thanks for the reply!